# How to configure docker-compose.yml and nginx conf file to read an external drive?

Tags: azure, docker, nginx, docker-compose, docker-volume

I have nginx in a docker container. My `docker-compose.yml` is like this (simplified):

```
nginx:
volumes:
  - /var/www/html:/www/:rw
  - /media/storage:/storage/:rw
```

Where `/var/www/html` is my website root and `/media/storage` is an external drive in my host machine (Azure).

Now I'm trying to point the website URL `example.com/downloads` to `/storage` but without success. My `nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf` is as following (simplified):

```
server {
listen       80  default;
server_name  example.com;

# this works
root   /www;
index  index.php;
 
# this get a 404 error
location  /downloads{
    root /storage;
}
```

}

But I get a 404 error for `example.com/downloads`. What am I forgetting here? The file permissions and owner to both paths are the same. I don't know if the bad configuration is in `example.com.conf` or in `docker-compose.yml`.  How should I configure these?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself using `alias /storage;` instead of `root /storage`.